# PHP check if date is expired

Tags: php, time, timestamp

i have an Array with this string value.

```
[VALIDUNTIL] => 28.08.23
```

Now i need to compare it with the todays date and check if the VALIDUNTIL date is in the same month and year as the today´s date
i looked for a while now but i cant find any solution.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) 
{
    $data[] = $row;
}


foreach($data as $ar) {
    if ($ar['VALIDUNTIL'] && $ar['VALIDUNTIL'] != null) {   
        if(strtotime($ar['VALIDUNTIL']) >= strtotime($date)) {
           
        }   
    }
```

When i try to do it with timestamps it cant read the VALIDUNTIL date and gives me the 1970 timestamp
strtotime seems not to work too.
tnx 4 help.

Comment: Better use the PHP DateTime classes, eg. `DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat()` which offers to specify a format.

Comment: May be `$ar['VALIDUNTIL']` is empty....? Do you display it to control....?

Comment: Not everything is out there done for you, occasionally you have to do something for yourself

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a database in that format, as far as I am aware that mean its in a VARCHAR or equivalent. Use a DATE data type and things are easier

Comment: Get the last 5 characters of your string and compare with `date('m.y')`

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right. With the date you propose and the format used, we don't know if it's 1923 or 2023 (even humanly speaking). And using timestamp for dates before 1970 doesn't work it seems to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) 
{
    if(!empty($row['VALIDUNTIL']) && !is_null($row['VALIDUNTIL'])){
       $valid_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['VALIDUNTIL']));
       $current_date = date('d-m-Y');
       if($valid_date >= $current_date ) {
          echo "True";
       }   
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works but I think that upstream the problem of the date format must be solved.

Comment: Yes you are correct but as mentioned in question, so I supposed valid date always greater then current date. so there will be no issue if date year would be 1923 or 2023

Answer (score 0):

Here are the PHP string conversions for time ref. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp

```
  echo(strtotime("now") . "<br>");
  echo(strtotime("3 October 2005") . "<br>");
  echo(strtotime("+5 hours") . "<br>");
  echo(strtotime("+1 week") . "<br>");
  echo(strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 5 seconds") . "<br>");
  echo(strtotime("next Monday") . "");
  echo(strtotime("last Sunday"));
```

You'd need to have both dates in the same format. The above is from : [https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp#:~:text=The%20strtotime()%20function%20parses,are%20mapped%20to%201970%2D2000](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp#:%7E:text=The%20strtotime()%20function%20parses,are%20mapped%20to%201970%2D2000).

if you echo   (strtotime($ar['VALIDUNTIL'])  and strtotime($date))  back to the screen then you can visually compare and check to see the format which you are using is the same for both dates and adjust accordingly.